# Apex differentiate between Lookup field to master detail field

Tags: apex, fields, data-types, sobjecttype

Is there a way to differ between regular `Lookup` field to a `MasterDetail` field?

When calling to `getDescribe()` on a field both of them holds the type of `REFERENCE`.

EDIT:

After further investigation, Is it possible that the field `is_updateable` is false on master detail but true on regular lookup?

Comment: is_updateable can be true on master-detail if the "allow reparenting" option is specified on the field.

Comment: great point @sfdcfox! learned something new

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to call `getRelationshipOrder()` from your describe. It will be null for a lookup, 0 or 1 for a Master-Detail relationship.